# Grails Command Object Not Work on Production Environment

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, command-objects

I am new in grails i am using commmand object for login validation.
it work fine in development environment but not work in production environment

```
   def login={LoginCommand loginCommand->
    if(!loginCommand.hasErrors()){
        ........
    }
    else{
        .............
    }
    render(view:"/student/login",model:[loginCommand:loginCommand])
}
```

Comment: How is it failing?  Please post the error message or stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

The code example posted by @Tomasz wouldn't make a difference.

Using methods or closures just works. Your problem lies elsewhere.

- Like @ataylor said, please post the **error message**, check your stacktraces, etc.
- Investigate the **differences** between your development environment and the production environment(external views, packaging issues, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

For controller actions prefer methods over closures. This should work:

```
def login(LoginCommand loginCommand) {
    if(!loginCommand.hasErrors()){
    ........
    } else {
    .............
    }
    render(view:"/student/login",model:[loginCommand:loginCommand])
}
```